# sqlalchemy returning result as Query object instead of MyModel type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
accounts = db.query(models.MyModel).filter(models.MyModel.id == user_id)
print(accounts)
```

results in

```
<sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query object at 0x1dbafd0>,
```

I expected a list or something of MyModel but i get back an object query. How can I get a list of MyModel instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to call `.all()` on that query. The object you are getting back is the unmaterialized query.